# Ease in 3 lines text

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

i would like to show three lines from a certain text with timestamp, but with ease in animation, my idea would be to show 3 lines of a document and they will replace each other with ease.

**For example:**

[0:02]Line 1
[0:03]Line 2
[0:04]Line 3

In the second 2:

(empty)
Line 1 -highlighted line-
Line 2

In the second 3:

Line 1
Line 2 -highlighted line-
Line 3

In the second 3:

Line 2
Line 3 -highlighted line-
(empty)

I amange to change everyline in the right time, but i would like to ease it for better view.
something like a Karaoke.

Thanks

this is my function where i reder the text:
text would have the value of the is the 3 lines text of the current time.
This function would be call by a listener of the elapsedTime.
_field.htmlText conteins the final text to be showed. this would be the field i want to ease.

```
    private function _renderText(text:String,style:Object=null):void {
        if (style) {
            _sheet.setStyle("p",style);
        } else { 
            _sheet.setStyle("p",_style);
        }
        // Place the text and align bottom
        _field.htmlText = '<p>'+text+'</p>';
        _field.y = _outline.y = -_field.height;
        _outline.graphics.clear();
    };
```

Comment: do you want to add an ease in/out effect on diosplaying the text? The ease effect then applies to the _alpha of the label?

Comment: This is not a code question. Please show you have at least started some actionscript that we can help you with.

Comment: I added the function that is doing the rendering of the text.

Comment: the ease effect would be aaply in the case to _field, everytime that is update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the answers to [Libraries for text animation in Flex / Actionscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189207/libraries-for-text-animation-in-flex-actionscript?rq=1) for some libraries which could help you.

[TextAnim](http://flupie.net/textanim/maker/) looks like a good bet to get you started.

Comment: Yeah... ill give a try to TextAnim!
It seems it has what i need